# Linker error in recursive union

Tags: c++, clang, linker-errors, c++14, debug-symbols

Given an extrimely simplificated code (I don't know how to reduce it even more):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

#define PP { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

struct descriptor
{
    std::size_t const s;
    bool const * c;
    bool const * d;
};

template< descriptor const & x, bool c, bool d, typename ...types >
union U;

template< descriptor const & x, bool c, bool d >
union U< x, c, d >
{
    static_assert(c);
    static_assert(d);

    U() PP
    ~U() PP
};

template< descriptor const & x, bool c, bool d, typename first, typename ...rest >
union U< x, c, d, first, rest... > // specialize against c and/or d values
{
    static constexpr std::size_t s = x.s - sizeof...(rest);
    using tail = U< x, x.c[s], x.d[s], rest... >;

    first head_;
    tail tail_{};

    U() PP
    ~U() { PP; /*tail_.~tail();*/ } // !!!!!!!
};

template< typename ...types >
struct V
{
    static constexpr bool c[sizeof...(types) + 1] = {std::is_trivially_constructible< types >{}..., true};
    static constexpr bool d[sizeof...(types) + 1] = {std::is_trivially_destructible< types >{}..., true};
    static constexpr descriptor x{sizeof...(types), c, d};
    U< x, x.c[0], x.d[0], types... > storage_;

    V() PP
    ~V() PP
};

template< typename ...types >
constexpr bool V< types... >::c[sizeof...(types) + 1];
template< typename ...types >
constexpr bool V< types... >::d[sizeof...(types) + 1];
template< typename ...types >
constexpr descriptor V< types... >::x;

int
main()
{
    struct S { S() { ; } ~S() { ; } };
    V< int, S, double > v;
    (void)v;
    S s;
    (void)s;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23566e157950b74e)

What it do is propagation of type traits through recursive `union` to use them somewhere in depth of recursion.

Currently the code gives linker error:

```
/tmp/main-ecd8fb.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2fa): undefined reference to `_ZN1UIL_ZN1VIJiZ4mainE1SdEE1xEELb1ELb1EJEED1Ev'
main.cpp:(.text+0x318): undefined reference to `_ZN1UIL_ZN1VIJiZ4mainE1SdEE1xEELb1ELb1EJdEED1Ev'
main.cpp:(.text+0x336): undefined reference to `_ZN1UIL_ZN1VIJiZ4mainE1SdEE1xEELb0ELb0EJS1_dEED1Ev'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But if I uncomment the line marked by exclamation marks, then liker error ceased to exist. It strange, because doing so I begin to use more symbols, then previously. `| c++filt -t` cant demangle this symbols and I can't infer what is wrong. Is it `clang` (version 3.7.0) bug or `ld` (GNU ld v2.22) bug or something else? How to detect the source of such errors in general? Which tools do you use?

Comment: It might help to try to reduce this to *minimal* code exhibiting the problem. It looks like a compiler bug for sure. A minimal example is nice to add with a bug report.

Comment: It works fine if I remove your pretty printing macro :p http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa62c144cac2338

Comment: Also, the symbols can be demangled if you add another leading underscore. They refer to the destructors of three different instantiations of `U`.

Comment: Also works without changes with a clang 3.8.0 I built from source.

Comment: Correction, pulled from master and rebuilt clang 3.8.0, and now I get the same unresolved symbols, so it does not seem resolved.